# Python - Pass the value of 'tk.Entry' value to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is loginPage function code

```
import tkinter as tk

def loginPage(self):
    login_screen = tk.Tk()
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x250")
    tk.Label(login_screen, text="Please enter login details").pack()
    tk.Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    tk.Label(login_screen, text="Username").pack()
    self.username_login_entry = tk.Entry(login_screen, textvariable="username")
    self.username_login_entry.pack()
    tk.Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    tk.Label(login_screen, text="Password").pack()
    self.password_login_entry = tk.Entry(login_screen, textvariable="password", show='*')
    self.password_login_entry.pack()
    tk.Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    tk.Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command=lambda x=self.username_login_entry.get(), y=self.password_login_entry.get(): mainLogin().verifyLogin(x, y)).pack()
    login_screen.mainloop()
```

here is my verify login function code

```
    def verifyLogin(self, uname, pword):

    try:
        import python_to_postgres as pp
        global checkUserEst
        print('user nad pass!!! ', uname, pword)
        #ETO UNG MAY PROBLEM DIKO MAKIHA UNG VALUE MULA TKINTER ENTRY
        self.checkUser = pp.pyPostgre().loginAuth(uname, pword)
```

is there any other ways on how to pass the value of an entry widgets into the other function?

Comment: You don't need the lambda arguments with default values.  Call those `.get()` inside the function instead.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using lambda. see the code below.

```
command=lambda a=0, b=0: mainLogin().verifyLogin(self.username_login_entry.get(), self.password_login_entry.get())
```

Comment: What the point of the two arguments `a` and `b`? They are not necessary at all.

Comment: I don't know how that works behind but  whenever I use lambda together with function that requires parameter/s it doesn't execute right away It will wait for the button to be pressed.